# In android what should be the image sizes in the folders drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdp, drawable-xhdpi

Tags: android

I am confused I have different drawable folders so that my application select images according to the phone screen. But I am confused about what will be the sizes of the images in different drawable folders?? please help

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Right click on res.
res->New -> Image Asset->Select Asset type - image

then browse your image.Android will automatically convert in different dpi.

Image dimension should be at least 196x196.